# Can brain waves be adjusted by music and affect phsical or mental health?

Tags: neurology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get high using binaural beats?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/can-i-get-high-using-binaural-beats)

Recently I've stumbled upon several brainwave synchronization audio programs ("Brainsync" for example).
Generally those programs claim to help you to improve your physical / mental health by listening to this audio programs once a day for a certain period.

Is there any scientific research or proof behind it?

Can a person really quit smoking, lose weight, or beat ADHD using those audio programs to sync his brain waves?

Comment: Woodstock should have been a study rather than an experiment.  =P