# Is Brainwave Entrainment for real?

Tags: productivity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get high using binaural beats?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/can-i-get-high-using-binaural-beats)

I've had days when I have a difficult time thinking and getting creative, and then I have other days where I have no problem at all being really really productive and creative.

And I heard something the other night on 60 minutes about brainwave syncronization and how people who have autism have a [difficult time getting the two hemispheres of their brain to sync-up](http://www.cbsnews.com/video/watch/?id=7385686n&tag=contentBody;storyMediaBox).

A few years ago I started using [Brainwave Entrainment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainwave_entrainment) software to help me fall asleep at night, and the software has other settings that are for other things like making you more productive, more creative etc...

I was just wondering how much of this was for real and how much of it was bunk...

Comment: I'm not completely sure if this is the right Stackexchange site to be asking this on.  If you have any other suggestions like some Neuroscience Stackexchange, please let me know.

Comment: skeptics might be an appropriate place for this.

Comment: Man, I didn't ask if binaural beats can get you high!??!?
But that said, it does seem to answer some of my questions...