# Does this audio of Delta Brain Waves help with mentality and emotion?

Tags: medical-science

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get high using binaural beats?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/can-i-get-high-using-binaural-beats)

In a youtube video ["Anti Depressant"1 hr Delta Binaural Beat Session (3.5Hz) ~ Pure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V-JtgXJ9Is&feature=related) , it says

> Video: Right Ear (90.0Hz) Left Ear (93.5Hz)
>
> 90 hz is associated with good feelings, security, well-being, and
>   balancing.
>
> Download this session FREE at
>   http://free-binaural-beats.com/delta-3-5hz/
>
> Delta Brain Waves Information ( O.5 to 4Hz) :
>
> - 0.5 Hz - Relaxation, helps soothe headaches
> - 0.5 - 1.5 Hz - Pain relief. Endorphin release
> - 0.9 Hz - Euphoric feeling
> - 1 Hz - Well being. Harmony and balance
> - 2.5 Hz - Production of endogenous opiates (pain killers, reduce anxiety)
> - 2.5 Hz - Relieves migraine pain. Produces endogenous opiates
> - 3.4 Hz - Helps achieve restful sleep
> - 3.5 Hz - Feeling of unity with everything. Whole being regeneration
> - 3.9 Hz - Self renewal, enhanced inner awareness
> - 4.0 Hz - Enkephalin release for reduced stress
> - 4.0 Hz - Allows brain to produce enkaphalins, all natural pain killer
> - 4.0 Hz - Full memory scanning. Releases enkephalins
> - 4.0 Hz - Vital for memory and learning. Problem solving, object naming
> - 1 - 3 Hz - Profound relaxation, restorative sleep. Tranquility and peace
>
> 3.5 - Feeling of unity with everything, accelerated language retention; enhancement of receptivity; (a remedy for) depression &
>   anxiety; Wholebeing regeneration, DNA stimulation
>
> ---------------- What are delta brainwaves? ---------------
>
> Delta brainwaves are considered the most relaxing brainwave frequency
>   range. Delta brainwaves are commonly associated with the deepest sleep
>   [stages 3 & 4] and a state of unconscious awareness. Delta brainwaves
>   are the lowest in brainwave frequency: ranging from 0 - 4 Hz, but are
>   the highest in amplitude. Delta brainwaves, like other slower
>   brainwave patterns, are generated in the right hemisphere, though they
>   may be observed in widespread patterns throughout various parts of the
>   brain. The delta brainwave range is associated with empathy, the
>   unconscious mind, and a decreased sense of awareness.
>
> --------------Benefits of increasing delta brainwaves-----------
>
> - Extreme bliss
> - Advanced healing of body and mind
> - Connection with unconscious mind
> - Deepest possible level of mind / body relaxation
> - Perfect intuition
> - Connecting with the spiritual body
> - Related to O.O.B.E , Astral Travel, ESP, and other phenomenon
> - Boosted immune system
> - Release of Anti-Aging hormones
>
> ---
>
> To find more detailed information on Binaural Beats and Brainwaves
>   please visit -
>
> http://www.scribd.com/doc/8179111/Binaural-Beats-Complete-with-ALL-info-about...
>
> To learn about research done with different frequencies please visit:
>
> http://www.lunarsight.com/freq.htm
>
> All Information provided by above links.

I can barely hear anything. I wonder if the audio does help with "good feelings, security, well-being, and balancing"?

Thanks!

Comment: **Related question:** http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/can-i-get-high-using-binaural-beats

Answer (score 0):

[Human's](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/sound/earsens.html) can't [hear that low](http://www.lsu.edu/deafness/HearingRange.html) in the [first place](http://music.columbia.edu/cmc/musicandcomputers/chapter2/02_03.php).

In case you didn't click any of the above, the range of the human ear is usually between 20Hz and 20kHz, but can be as low as 12Hz.

You can't hear any of your Delta brainwaves.

Comment: Without touching the validity of the assertions quoted in the question with a bargepole, my understanding of the idea of binaural beats is that playing waveforms of slightly different frequencies in either ear creates an infrasonic response in the brain, due to the waveforms in either ear going in and out of phase with each other.

Comment: @RichardTerrett - That doesn't make any more sense to me than the initial question. I am not aware of any mechanism by which infrasonic frequencies - particularly infrasonic Beat frequencies - would affect neurochemistry. If someone suggests one, I can check it, but otherwise I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Hello, please take a look at [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19616993) paper, linked in Monkey Tuesday's answer to the referred duplicated question. I realise that this question is closed but I thought you'd find it interesting.