# Can the special sound frequency make addiction?

Tags: neurology, music, addiction

Supposedly, for certain music track are used any frequencies that the human ear can not hear , but the brain can. And this the frequencies create pleasant feelings, which is why more people choose a song. What do you think about it?

Links:

vice.com/read/i-tried-to-get-high-using-digital-drugs

thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=22591.0

Comment: Can you give a link to a specific claim here? I'd like to see what mechanism they propose the brain is using to hear.

Comment: Ah. If the question is "does it work?" you might find the answer on [this question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/18694/19407) about binaural beats. If the question is "do they intentionally put these sounds in commercial music?" (whether it works or not), you might want to state that more clearly.

Comment: Please edit the link into your question; comments on this site can go away.